# Kafka Connect 5.5.0 - Unable to reset max.request.size

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

In confluent-5.5.0 - I am unable to change the max.request.size , which always defaults to max.request.size = 1048576 in the ProducerConfig.

The following are the parameters I have already tried with noluck:

**confluent-5.5.0/etc/kafka/producer.properties**

```
  max.request.size=15728640
  producer.max.request.size=15728640
```

**confluent-5.5.0/etc/kafka/server.properties**

```
  message.max.bytes=15728640
  replica.fetch.max.bytes=15728640
  max.request.size=15728640
  fetch.message.max.bytes=15728640
```

**/data/confluent-5.5.0/etc/kafka/consumer.properties**

```
  max.partition.fetch.bytes=15728640
```

**confluent-5.5.0/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties**

```
  max.request.size=15728640
```

NOTE : None of these values is getting updated in the connect.log

1. I have stop/started confluent-5.5.0 , even destroyed the previous images and restarted.

Am i missing something ?

**The following i have also tried after the information from comment :**

**/data/confluent-5.5.0/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties**

producer.override.max.request.size=15728640
consumer.override.max.partition.fetch.bytes=15728640

**/data/confluent-5.5.0/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties**

producer.override.max.request.size=15728640
consumer.override.max.partition.fetch.bytes=15728640

Still in the max.request.size has not got changed.

( Solved )Based on the inputs :

I have added the above configuration in the connect
or configuration. And also changed the policy from none to ALL. Which applied the configuration changes properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those files are not used by Connect.

- `server` is for the Apache Kafka Broker only
- `consumer|producer` are for the `kafka-console` utilities
- `kafka-rest` is for the Confluent REST Proxy  only

You need to use `connect-distributed.properties` or `connect-standalone.properties` and notice that you need to [additionally set the property correctly](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#producer-and-consumer-overrides) using prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for info updated question with what i have tried

Comment: The `.override.` section is only in the connector configuration, not the worker configuration

Comment: This setting here works for me if placed in the `commect-distributed.properties`: `producer.max.request.size=15728640`

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to set configuration in kafka connect proprties file :
add the following in distributed or standalone connect properties file

```
producer.max.request.size=157286400
consumer.max.request.size=157286400
max.request.size=157286400
```

and it will work !!!